# How to get the value of a html span element in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a span element in my html as shown below containing a value 0 :

```
<span class="personcart">0</span>
```

I have written a jquery to add 1 to the number stored in the span element.When I am on a button which is span element containing class as addtocartbt. I am adding 1 to the zero value in the span element with class personcart and storing 1 as the content of span element with class personcart. But when I am again click the span element with class addtocartbt, it alerting the value as 11 which is previously stored in the span element with class name personcart. Actually it should be 1 only not 11.

```
var totalsum = parseInt($("span.personcart").text());
$("span.addtocartbt").click(function()
{




      alert(totalsum);
      var intg = 1;

     if(totalsum == 0){



        var totalsum   = parseInt(totalsum) + parseInt(intg);
        //$("span.personcart").html("0");
        alert(totalsum);
        $("span.personcart").html(totalsum);


      }
      else{
            alert("okkkk!!!");
            var totalsum = parseInt($("span.personcart").text());
            //$("span.personcart").html("0");
            var totalsum   = parseInt(totalsum) + parseInt(intg);
            alert(totalsum);
            $("span.personcart").html(totalsum);

      }

      /*var totalsum = 0;
      alert(totalsum);
      var totalsum   = parseInt(totalsum) + 1;
      alert(totalsum);*/

});
```

Can anyone say how to do this ?

Comment: span has `no value` use `.text()` to get the text of span

Comment: i have used .text() but it is displaying 11 not as 1.

Comment: the problem is not in assigning but in initializing. initialize the `var totalsum` outside the click event so it will add up. when you click it is always resetting the value

Comment: its working..when click first time, it replaces the content of span element with value 1. But when it is again clicked, it is taking 11 and again adding 1 to it and display it as 12 instead of 2.

Comment: please do my previous comment and see if this one fixes the problem

Comment: No..Still it is not taking 1 but it is taking 11 and adding it with 1 and displaying as 12

Comment: can you update your OP

Comment: update the original post

Comment: i have updated the original post....

Comment: provided an answer hope this clears the problem out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var totalsum = parseInt($("span.personcart").text());
$("span.addtocartbt").click(function() {
  alert(totalsum);
  var intg = 1;
  if (totalsum == 0) {
    totalsum = parseInt(totalsum) + parseInt(intg);//dont initialize
    //$("span.personcart").html("0");
    alert(totalsum);
    $("span.personcart").html(totalsum);
  } else {
    alert("okkkk!!!");
    totalsum = parseInt($("span.personcart").text());
    //$("span.personcart").html("0");
    totalsum = parseInt(totalsum) + parseInt(intg);//dont initialize
    alert(totalsum);
    $("span.personcart").html(totalsum);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="personcart">0</span>
<span class="addtocartbt">addtocartbt</span>
```

Commented the places where you reinitialize the variable do check the comment

Answer (score 1):

it's working already

```js
$("span.addtocartbt").click(function()
{



     var totalsum = parseInt($("span.personcart").text());
      alert(totalsum);
      var intg = 1;

     if(totalsum == 0){



        var totalsum   = parseInt(totalsum) + parseInt(intg);
        //$("span.personcart").html("0");
        alert(totalsum);
        $("span.personcart").html(totalsum);


      }
      else{
            alert("okkkk!!!");
            var totalsum = parseInt($("span.personcart").text());
            //$("span.personcart").html("0");
            var totalsum   = parseInt(totalsum) + parseInt(intg);
            alert(totalsum);
            $("span.personcart").html(totalsum);

      }



 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="personcart">0</span>
<span class="addtocartbt">Add To Cart</span>
```